# How to pass build arguments to docker build command?

Tags: docker

I have a command like this:
`docker build -f ${DOCKERFILE} ${BUILD_ARGS} -t ${IMAGE} ${BUILD_CONTEXT}`

When I pass these environment variables it works:

```
IMAGE_SUBNAME: 'frontend'
DOCKERFILE: ./frontend/Dockerfile
BUILD_CONTEXT: ./frontend
```

But when I try to pass these, it throw me error (see below):

```
IMAGE_SUBNAME: 'frontend'
DOCKERFILE: ./frontend/Dockerfile
BUILD_CONTEXT: ./frontend
BUILD_ARGS: ENV=${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}        // CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG equals to "dev"
```

> "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.

I have already read a lot of articles, but I can't find my mistake. Hope to get help.

Comment: docker build -f ${DOCKERFILE} --build-arg ${BUILD_ARGS} -t ${IMAGE} ${BUILD_CONTEXT} --- and ${BUILD_ARGS} should be only one value so --build-arg test=hallo --build-arg test2=hallo2

Comment: So I can write `--build-arg ENV=${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}` in `BUILD_ARGS`, can't I?

Comment: yes you can , what is in ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} ?

Comment: There can be `dev` or `prod` value (string)

Comment: then yes that should works

Comment: Yes, it works. I have tried this command before, but I wrote `--build-args` instead of `--build-arg`. You can post your answer and I will accept it. Thank you for help)

Comment: No need, you are welcome :)